# Mutex or not to Mutex?

Tags: pthreads, mutex

I have an array A of length 1024 and I have 4 threads, the first will work on indexes 0 to 255, the second on 256 to 511, the third on 512 to 767, the last will work on indexes 768 to 1023.
Do I need a Mutex for that ?

Comment: Is the array 100% guaranteed not be resized, and not move around in memory, while the threads do their work. If not then don't need a mutex.

Comment: It might be easier to answer with a few more details: the array is genuinely a C-style array (I'm making a guess from the pthreads tag)? If it's one of the STL types then which, and are you mutating the values in the array?

Comment: @Tommy no its a C++ , Sorry I am new to all this. I think I should have tagged lpthreads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need a Mutex for that?

Assuming something like:

```
int A[1024];
```

Short answer (for C): No.